# How do I create this numpy tensor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mnist

I am working on the MNIST dataset. *images* stores the image data and is of size 60000 x 28 x 28. I have another numpy array, *labels* storing one-hot encoded labels of size 60000 x 10. How do I build a numpy array of rank 4 containing image and label data?

I tried using cross-product, and dot-product. But, neither of them worked.

```py
T = images[:,:,:] * labels [:,:]
```

Comment: what do you mean by numpy array of rank 4?

Comment: So, I have the two variables - *images* and *labels*, and I am supposed to combine them into a 4 dimensional array - *T* such that, I get the 60000 x 28 x 28 data from *images* and the 60000 x 10 data from *labels*

Comment: The combined array has to be of size 60000 x 28 x 28 x10

Comment: with all the values from the original *labels* and *images* array

Comment: the 60000*10 is one hove vector for each image. Now you want to create 10 images for each image ie  `1  x 28 x 28 x 10` what exactly do you want the values of `[:,:,:,0]` to be? all zeros if the label is not 0?

Comment: Yes, I'd want it to be all 0s if the image does not have that label.

Comment: `T = images[:,:,:,None] * labels[:,None,None]` is what you are looking for

Comment: Hey, I got it now. The T would be images[:,:,:,None]*labels [:,None,None,None]. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: you cannot have `3 Nones` that will make labels to have 5 dimensions hence icompatible multiplication, check what I wrote

Comment: Ah, yes. I got it now. Had to write this one out because I didn't focus well. Thanks a lot, mate.